# MQL5 calculate the Stochastic value for previous 15 candle or 15 minutes

Tags: mql5, metatrader5

I am trying to access the previous values or the stochastic of the chart in MQL5. But I only know how to calculate for the current.

What I am trying to do is:

```
int stochastic_output = iStochastic(_Symbol,PERIOD_M1,5,3,3,MODE_SMA,STO_LOWHIGH);
```

But I don't know how I can get the value of the previous 15 candles or the previous 3 minutes. Kindly, help me how to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//--- inputs
input int Candles=15;
input int NeededCandle=3;
// --- global variables
int stoch_handle;

int OnInit(){
    stoch_handle=iStochastic(_Symbol,PERIOD_M1,5,3,3,MODE_SMA,STO_LOWHIGH);
    if(stoch_handle==INVALID_HANDLE)
        return(INIT_FAILED);
}

void OnTick(){
    double main[],signal[];
    ArrayResize(main,Candles);
    ArraySetAsSeries(main,true);
    ArrayResize(signal,Candles);
    ArraySetAsSeries(signal,true);
    if(CopyBuffer(stoch_handle,MAIN_LINE,0,Candles,main)!=Candles)
        return;
    if(CopyBuffer(stoch_handle,SIGNAL_LINE,0,Candles,signal)!=Candles)
        return;
    printf("%i - main=%.2f, signal=%.2f",__LINE__,main[NeededCandle-1],signal[NeededCandle-1]);
}
```

Comment: It didn't help. The code is showing the current value only and not the past 15 candles values.

Comment: check that in tester (add `ExpertRemove()` at end) so that you will see same indicator settings. `NeededCandle=1 for last, 3 for bar #2 (0,1,2) etc

Comment: I didn't understood. say I was thinking to calculate the last 15 candles, but what I see in the output of `printf()` is the value corresponding to the current candles. Can you please let me know why is this happening? I will share image if needed, of my test,with you for clarification.

Comment: check the image: https://ibb.co/gxFPzc  Is it possible that I get the last 15 candles data in an array format or like  a buffer so that I will come to know that the values are stochastic for last 15 candles? Is it feasible?

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way to do that.

What you need is to copy the data per minute of previous 15 candles using `CopyBuffer`.
See the example:

```
double K[],D[];
ArraySetAsSeries(K,true);
ArraySetAsSeries(D,true);
int stochastic_output = iStochastic(_Symbol,PERIOD_M1,5,3,3,MODE_SMA,STO_LOWHIGH);  
CopyBuffer(stochastic_output,0,0,15,K);
CopyBuffer(stochastic_output,1,0,15,D);
Print("K size:  ",ArraySize(K));
Print("D size:  ",ArraySize(D));
```

Output of the above:

```
K Size:  15
D Size:  15
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This is excellent and working the best for me. Thank you. And yes it the simplest...

Comment: Simpler is better, although it gets compilation errors in the  latest MT5 build and also OP is asking for the values on the previous 15 candles, not the array size, here's a small fix:  void OnTick()
{double K[], D[];
int stochastic_output = iStochastic(_Symbol, PERIOD_M1, 5, 3, 3, MODE_SMA, STO_LOWHIGH);
if (stochastic_output != INVALID_HANDLE)
{   ArraySetAsSeries(K, true);
    ArraySetAsSeries(D, true);
    CopyBuffer(stochastic_output, 0, 0, 15, K);
    CopyBuffer(stochastic_output, 1, 0, 15, D);
    printf("K value=%.2f, D value=%.2f",__LINE__,K[0],D[0]);
}
}